# SCSS Lint: Force only classnames to be used as a selector

Tags: sass, bem, scss-lint

I have a `.scss-lint.yml` file containing all the rules I want to use in my project.

One thing we enforce in our SCSS is that only classes are targeted, as per BEM documentation.

Because this is not covered in my `.scss-lint.yml`, it stands currently as a sort of unofficial rule.

It's not immediately obvious from the [scss-lint page](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint). Is there some rule I can apply to my YML that will show an error if anything but a classname is used as a selector?

Answer (score 0):

There is the idSelector linter https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/lib/scss_lint/linter/README.md#idselector that enforces the use of classes vs Ids in stylesheets.

But if you use BEM, I would advise to enable SelectorFormat and pass in the BEM convention - https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/lib/scss_lint/linter/README.md#selectorformat

So your `.scss-int.yml` would contain

`SelectorFormat:
    enabled: true
    convention: BEM`

and on top of that could use

`NameFormat:
    enabled: true
    convention: BEM`

Every linter is documented here https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/lib/scss_lint/linter/README.md#linters

Hope it helps.